# Is it possible for a right triangle whose vertices are lattice points to have legs that aren't parallel to the axes?

Tags: calculus, geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, area

This is a problem from Apostol calculus vol I. It originally asks to prove that the area of any right triangle with vertices at lattice points have area given by
$$Z+\frac12B-1$$
where $Z$ is the number of lattice points lying inside the triangle, $B$ the number of lattice points lying on the perimeter.

It is particularly easy to prove that if the triangle has the perpendicular and base parallel to the axes.

My question is:

> Is it at all possible for triangles with lattice points as vertices to have a different configuration of the sides (i.e., base and perp. not parallel to the axes)?  If not, how do i prove it?

Comment: Hint: Perpendicular lines have negative-reciprocal slopes.

Comment: Something like $(0,0), (2,1), (-1,2)$?

Comment: @Blue So if (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) are the points then [(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)]*[(y3-y2)/(x3-x2)]=-1 . This means y3-y2=-(x3-x2)(x1-x2)/(y1-y2). There seems to be infinite possibilities for integer (x,y)

Comment: @Suprativ: I'm not sure I understand your concern. If there are "infinite possibilities", then your question is answered overwhelmingly in the affirmative. (Note that there are "infinite possibilities" for right triangles whose legs are parallel to the axes, too.)

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) is the general case.

Comment: @Suprativ The title does not match the body of the question. Title asks about "*legs*", the question asks about "*sides (i.e. base and perp)*". Which one is it?

Comment: @dxiv: Blame my edit for the legs-vs-sides terminological mismatch; I was aiming for concision in the title, and I apologize if I introduced confusion instead. That said, it seemed (and seems) to me that "legs" and "sides (i.e. base and perp)" agree in connotation in this context. (Certainly, a hypotenuse can be considered a "base", but the corresponding "perp" (which I take to mean "altitude") wouldn't be a "side".)

Comment: @Blue Looking at the original wording, I don't think your edit introduced *additional* ambiguity, but I am still not sure whether OP's "*sides (i.e., base and perp)*" is supposed to mean $2$ sides (one leg + the other perpendicular leg) vs. $3$ sides (a "*base*" which could be the hypotenuse + two perpendicular legs). FWIW there are two answers posted at this time, one for each interpretation.

Comment: @dviv: what you call "legs" is normally in many countries called catheti. It is clear what the OP means by "pendicular and the base". I do not know where he/she is from, but I guess that is what catheti are called there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The [site](https://projecteuler.net/problem=91) provides pictures of 14 examples when each coordinate of two vertices lies between 0 and 2 inclusive. There are two examples where perpendicular sides are not parallel to the axes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a Pythagorean triple if all sides are
multiples of some valid hypotenuse, the primitive values of which are listed
[here](https://oeis.org/search?q=hypotenuse&language=english&go=Search).

One that comes to mind is $\space(75,100,125)=25\times(3,4,5)\space$ and
$$(21^2+72^2=45^2+60^2=75^2)\\
(28^2+96^2=60^2+80^2=100^2)\\
(75^2+100^2=117^2+44^2=125^2)
$$
The area is $\space 3750.\quad$
If one vertex is at the origin $\space (0,0)\space $ and another at
$\space (60,45),\space $ the third vertex can be at
$(-60,80),\space (0,125),\space  (60,-80), \text{or }(120,-35).\quad$ The drawing below shows $\space 4\space$ possible locations of the long leg, and $\space 2 \space$ locations for a hypotenuse not aligned with the axes.  I don’t know how to find the number of internal lattice points but I believe, for the perimeter, it is $\space3\cdot 25=75.$

There are infinite other solutions and they only need to meet the restrictions in the first sentence above.

[image]

Comment: It's easier than that: nothing in the problem statement requires the side lengths to be integers or even that they be commensurable.

Comment: @David K     The use of Pythagorean triples (integer sides) simply  makes it unmistakeable that solutions exist.

Comment: Just take $(0,0),$ $(p,q),$ $(-q,p)$ for any non-zero integers $p,q.$ Use the inner product (or observe that one slope is the negative reciprocal of the other) to confirm that two sides are orthogonal.